# Meteor: Re-use template with different data

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor, handlebars.js

I've got a few templates which list items (log lines, users) and style them accordingly in tables. Now I've added a "search" page which searches for a string in different item types and displays them on one page. In terms of layout, I want to reuse the original templates, but obviously with the data returned by the search.

**How can I do that without duplicating the template itself in the HTML file?**

Put another way: How can I use the actual data from the top-level template in the sub-templates.

Small example:

```
<template name="user_list">
{{#each user_list}}
</template>

<template name="users">
{{> user_list}}
</template>

<template name="search">
{{> user_list}}
{{> group_list}}
</template>
```

In .coffee:

```
 Template.users.user_list = ->
     [a,b,c,d]

 Template.search.user_list = ->
     [b,c]
```

Maybe this is an easy one, which would show how little I really understood about Meteor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the template you want to use inside the `{{#each}}` statement. Then each item in the array will be the context for that inner template.

### HTML file

```
<template name="users">
    <ul>
    {{#each UserArr}}
        {{> userItem}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="userItem">
    <li><a href="/edituser/{{_id}}">{{username}}</a> {{profile.name}}</li>
</template>
```

### JS file

```
Template.users.UserArr = function()
{
    return Meteor.users.find({});
};
```

Answer (score -1):

another solution is to put your request in a Session attribute and check for its existence when querying for the users. By default `Session.get("userQuery")` would return `undefined` but once you enter something in the search field you change that with `Session.set("userQuery", {type: "something"})`

Now in the coffeescript you could say:

```
Template.users.user_list = ->
   if(Session.get("userQuery"))
     [a,b,c,d]
   else
     [b,c]
```

or alternatively use a MiniMongo query because it is much nicer :-)

the nice thing is that your HTML will rerender because it is reactive to the Session's content.